# Android keep Orientation from app Start

Tags: android, screen-orientation

Is it somehow possible to set the orientation of the app depending on which orientation was used when the app was started?

**Example**

By that i mean lets say user started my app in Landscape. O would like it to save that state and dont let the user change the orientation by turrning the phone ( I want to lock it, until user re-runs application and from there app agains checks if the user started it in landscape or portrait )

**CODE (so far)**

```
Configuration newConfig = getResources().getConfiguration();
  if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
             Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             // set background for landscape through app
     } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           // set background for portrait through app
  }
```

This was something i found here on SO. Could i do it like this? Put this in my first activity and then use the orientation state from here for the rest of the activites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences to store a value that will be saved even if the app is closed.
Just make a class SaveOrientation :

```
public class SaveOrientation {

    static final String ORIENTATION = "orientation";

    static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ctx) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    }

    // value will be between 0 and 1
    public static void setOrientation(Context ctx, int value) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
        editor.putInt(ORIENTATION, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String getOrientation(Context ctx) {
        return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(ORIENTATION, "");
    }

}
```

And then in your MainActivity :

```
int portrait = 0;
int landscape = 1;
.
.
.
// in your onCreate :
Configuration newConfig = getResources().getConfiguration();
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
         SaveOrientation.setOrientation(this,portrait);
 }else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
         SaveOrientation.setOrientation(this,landscape);
}
applyOrientation();
.
.
.
// method applyOrientation
private void applyOrientation(){
   int orientation = SaveOrientation.getOrientation(this);

   if(orientation == portrait){
     this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

   }else if (orientation == landscape){
     this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it by using ActivityInfo class.

```
ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Check ActivityInfo [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html)

```
Button buttonSetPortrait = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setPortrait);
Button buttonSetLandscape = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setLandscape);

buttonSetPortrait.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
   }

});

buttonSetLandscape.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
   }

});
```

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/08/set-screen-orientation-programmatically.html

In case anyone would like to obtain meaningful orientation description (like that passed to onConfigurationChanged(..) with those reverseLandscape, sensorLandscape and so on), simply use getRequestedOrientation()

Comment: Thank you for mentioning ActivityInfo didnt knew about that, but i went with Davids approach. And for explaination + example really helpful